# How can I apply queue call confirm in Asterisk using the files .conf

Tags: extjs, queue, asterisk, confirm, agent

How can I apply queue call confirm in Asterisk using the files .conf

For example:

- The client call to the ext 100
- two agents could receive the call
- one of them take it
- The agent listen the announce that say "The call is for sales, 1 to accept the call or 0 to not
- If the agent say yes, receive the call
- If the agent say no, the call is ringing to the other agent

Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that via call privacy macro.

In freepbx you have that option in web. If you use plain asterisk you should use M(macroname) param for **Dial** command and create correct context yourself.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Dial